# Misunderstand the usage of this function in class?

Tags: c++

I am facing this type of function:

```
class Menu: public Activity
{
private:

   // something defined here

public:
   Menu();
   ~Menu();

   // something defined here
}
```

I am learning C++ and can not understand of how "~Menu()" function works? When will we need this function? Is this something relevant to overload function? Can anyone explain me? Thank you.

Comment: Read a book. Destructors are covered in every elementary book.

Comment: This is elementary stuff that is better to be learnt via a book.

Comment: See [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is the destructor. It takes care of any cleanup you would like to do when the object is going out of scope.

```
Menu();   // Constructor
~Menu();  // Destructor
```

Depending on how trivial the class is, you may even need to define a constructor and destructor, as the compiler will generate them for you. There are, of course, plenty of examples of cases where you need to do some specific work, so you can define them if you'd like.